# How to reload cmake targets

Tags: cmake

Following is the my scenario. I have one top level *CMakeList.txt* and another 2 internal *CMakeList.txt*. In top level cmake I have 3 custom targets that are `copy`, `build`, `copyandbuild`. As name specifies `make copy` copies the source directories (i.e dir1, dir2) to ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}. `make build` creates libs and executables. `make copyandbuild` (copy+build).

Running `cmake ..` from build directory completes successfully.

If I run `make copyandbuild` it is copying to ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} but at the time of build it is showing error that

```
No rule to make target `dir1/libmylib.so', needed by `CMaketargetdbuild'.  Stop
```

- MyProject

  - dir1

    - CMakeLists.txt
  - dir2

    - CMakeLists.txt
  - CMakeLists.txt

It is working if i execute commands in below order.

- cmake ..
- make copyandbuild
- cmake ..
- make build

**My requirement** is it should work with out running cmake and make build again as copyandbuild doing the same work.

Top level CMakeLists.txt:

```
  cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

  cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
  set(RE_BUILD make rebuild_cache)
  set(OUTPUT_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/../)


  if(EXISTS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dir1)
  message(WARNING "Found dir1 dir")
  add_subdirectory(dir1 EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
  else()
  message(WARNING "Couldn't find dir1 directory ")
  endif()


  if(EXISTS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dir2)
  add_subdirectory(dir2 EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
  else()
  message(WARNING "Couldn't find dir2 directory")
  endif()

  set(MOVE_LIB_COMMAND mv src/myapp . && mv dir1/mylib .)
  set(COPY_COMMAND cp -r ../sourceCode1 ../dir1 && cp -r ../sourceCode2 ../dir2)

  set(CLEAN_DIR1_COMMAND cmake -E remove_directory ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dir1)
  set(CLEAN_DIR2_COMMAND cmake -E remove_directory ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dir2)

  set(SET_SLEEP sync)

  #Copy command
  add_custom_target(
  copy ${COPY_COMMAND}
  COMMAND ${RE_BUILD} 
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
  )
  #Compilation
  add_custom_target(
  build
  COMMAND ${MOVE_LIB_COMMAND}
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
  DEPENDS mylib myapp
  )

  #copy and compile
  add_custom_target(
  copyandbuild  
  COMMAND ${MOVE_LIB_COMMAND} 
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
  DEPENDS copy mylib myapp
  )

  add_custom_command(TARGET copy POST_BUILD
               COMMAND ${SET_SLEEP} 
  )
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -std=c++11")
```

dir1 CMake is :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -std=c++11")


include_directories(
${MY_APP_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

link_directories(
${MY_APP_LIBDIR}
)

add_library(mylib
SHARED 
com/*.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(mylib myapp_lib)
```

dir2 CMake is :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -std=c++11")
include_directories(
${MY_APP_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)
link_directories(
${MY_APP_LIBDIR}
)
```

Comment: can you share the content of the CmakeLists.txt in a stripped down manner?

Comment: Please, cleanup your code snippet: make variables consistent (e.g., you set variable `RE_BUILD_COMMAND`, but use `RE_BUILD`), remove definitions of variables which are not used in the snippet. As far as I understand from the code, you expect DEPENDS option of the [add_custom_target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/add_custom_target.html) to add dependency from other *targets*. But it actually adds **dependencies from files**. For add dependencies between targets, use command [add_dependencies](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/command/add_dependencies.html#command:add_dependencies).

Answer (score 2):

You are using CMake in a way that prevents its proper function.  By explicitly invoking shell commands in many places, when you could use CMake built in features, you are robbing CMake of any context that it could use to build your programs.  Also, using wildcards like `*.cpp` in CMake is considered bad practice.  And you have a number of duplicate statements--you do not need `cmake_minimum_required()` or setting compiler flags other than at the top level.

In short, your `CMakeLists.txt` at the top level should look more like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -std=c++11")

add_subdirectory(dir1 EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
```

You should not need to copy source files around--just build them from where they are, for example your `dir1/CMakeLists.txt` might be:

```
add_library(mylib
  SHARED
  sourceCode1/mylib.cpp
)
```

Keep it simple.  Get it working.  Then ask questions if you need to add missing features.

Comment: Thanks! for you Suggestions, actually here i have used copying only for simple understanding purpose,in real time dir1 and dir2 will be generated from some external applications.Once generation is done my copyandbuild command should be able to compile the generated code.

Comment: @venkat2010: then you should reformulate your question into a fully working but minimal example.  Since we don't have your code generator, you could use a simple `bash` script to write a .cpp file or whatever.